# I am using EveryPlay api to record video and can not record sound

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, recording, fmod, everyplay

The recommended api for sound is FMOD which is paid. If there a possible free api for sound which can replace the standard simple audio engine of cocos2d?

Answer (score 0):

I've personally tried to look for some alternatives as well but no luck, it
seems pretty much every library wraps some audio code around OpenAL or AVFoundation

But the good thing is, there's OpenAL and CocosDenshion support coming to
Everyplay soon, meaning there's no need to change existing code. :)

It's a work in progress atm, but I'd expect a public release within two weeks

Comment: Other things came up blocking the audio release back in February. We just released Everyplay SDK 1.3 that now supports OpenAL and CocosDenshion.. we also provide a minimal custom sound API for those who prefer not to use either OpenAL, CocosDension or other sound engines for effects and background music.